# JQuery list plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I´m searchin a JQuery plugin. When I type in a text into a textfield and press a button, the value of the textfield should be shown in a list beneath the textfield.

Does anyone know such a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you will find such a specific plugin, but you could write one yourself. Here's something to get you started (far from perfect, but it should get you on the right track):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.addToList = function(opts) {
        var input = this;
        opts.button.click(function() {
            opts.list.append("<li>" + input.val() + "</li>");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" id="example">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

You would call the plugin like this:

```
$("#example").addToList({
    button: $("#btn"),
    list: $("#list")
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2EFTZ/1/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult to write it yourself

```
 <input type="text" id="thisbox" />
 <button id="thisbutton" value="click me"></button>
 <ul id="listme"></ul>
```

and the jQuery

```
 $("#thisbutton").click(function(){
     var valuebox = $("#thisbox").val();
     if(valuebox.length > 0){
          $("#listme").append("<li>" + valuebox  + "</li>");
     }
 });
```